# How do I fix audio not always autoplaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Sometimes the autoplay doesn't work. This is set to play a song automatically and refresh the page to get the next song because I couldn't figure out how to get it to call my php again and get a new song. It always works when you click play. It just doesn't do like it should and autoplay.

Why does autoplay sometimes not work?

```
The error from console when autoplay doesn't work:

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException line 26:
        25  $('audio').get(0).load();
        26  $('audio').get(0).play();
        27  document.getElementById("songName").innerHTML =
```

'http://192.168.1.180' + data;

An error that always appears on page load:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined
    at radio.html:15
            14  <br />
            15  <script>document.write(url);</script>
            16  <button onclick="skip()">Skip me</button>
```

Example of input given through ajax when it happens:

```
http://192.168.180/uploads/Music/Ive_Gone_Away_Black_Label_Society_Catacombs_of_the_Black_Vatican_2014.mp3
```

```html
 <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <center>
        <?php echo $data ?>
        <audio id="playMusic" controls autoplay>
          <source id="source" src="" type="audio/mp3">
          Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
        <br />
        <button onclick="skip()">Skip me</button>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $.ajax({
            url: 'radio.php',
            data: { attr1: 'value1' },
            success: function (data) {
              console.log(data);
              $('audio #source').attr('src', data);
              $('audio').get(0).load();
              $('audio').get(0).play();
            }
          });
          playMusic.onended = function () {
            window.location.reload();
          };
          function skip() {
            window.location.reload();
          }
        </script>
      </center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I have tried everything I could think of and cannot get 100% successful auto play.
The reason for this I believe is in Google Chrome (Which I am using) has basically disabled it. I tried to get around it by simulating a click but it doesn't work until you physically click on the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ❌ Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first. [https://goo.gl/xX8pDD](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

The answer is, it worked fine. It's just blocked by chrome itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `autoplay="autoplay"` attribute to `audio` tag.

```
<audio id="playMusic" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">     
<source src="music.mp3" />   
</audio>
```